# Accessing an angular factory object without DI

Tags: angularjs

How do you access an angular factory object without using DI that angular provides? For example, I want to have a separate script that adds some server properties to a factory object  outside of angular (in a .cshtml file). I don't want to assign the factory object to a separate variable as that would create a global variable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand 100% what you want to achieve, but if I'm not mistaken you want to get a hold of the factory object "outside" of the angular context.

```
var factoryObject = angular.injector(['nameOfYourModule']).get('factoryname');
```